# Restlet: How does one use ClientResource with an Application

Tags: java, json, restlet, chunked-encoding

We have a RESTlet application that creates an `Application` object and then uses CLAP to serve static files (via `LocalReference.createClapReference`)

Now, we'd like to turn off chunking by using `ClientResource#setRe​questEntityBuffering`, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where to integrate that into our RESTlet. How does it fit in with the `Application` and Router objects?

Should I create a subclass of `LocalReference.CLAP_CLASS` and somehow stick it in there?

Suggestions?

```
public static void createRestServer(ApplicationContext appCtx, String propertiesPath) throws Exception {

  // Create a component
  Component component = new Component();
  component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8081);
  component.getClients().add(Protocol.FILE);
  component.getClients().add(Protocol.CLAP);

  Context context = component.getContext().createChildContext();
  RestServer application = new RestServer(context);

  application.getContext().getParameters().add("useForwardedForHeader", "true");

  application.getContext().getAttributes().put("appCtx", appCtx);
  application.getContext().getAttributes().put("file", propertiesPath);

  // Attach the application to the component and start it
  component.getDefaultHost().attach(application);
  component.start();
}

private RestServer(Context context) {
  super(context);
}

public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot() {
  Router router = new Router(getContext());

  // we then have a bunch of these
  router.attach("/accounts/{accountId}", AccountFetcher.class); //LIST Account level
  // blah blah blah

  // finally some stuff for static files:
  //
  Directory directory = new Directory(getContext(),
     LocalReference.createClapReference(LocalReference.CLAP_CLASS, "/"));
  directory.setIndexName("index.html");
  router.attach("/", directory);

  return router;
}
```

Comment: Directory uses DirectoryServerResource under the hood, which requests a ClientDispatcher from the context.  This automatically selects the correct Client Connector for your request protocol (CLAP).  I'd fiddle with that or the context params.